# How to indicate to rust to move a value to another scope?

Tags: rust, ownership

The following code fails to compile due to the compiler thinking that `s` remains in the scope of `main` instead of moving into the scope of `spawn`. Why doesn't the compiler understand that `s` doesn't need to be tied to the outer scope and can be moved to the scope of `spawn`?

```
struct MyStruct {}

impl MyStruct {
    async fn run(&self) {
        println!("Hello");
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct{};
    tokio::task::spawn(s.run());
}

main()
```

Error:

```
[E0597] Error: `s` does not live long enough
    ╭─[command_21:1:1]
    │
 11 │     let s = S{};
    ·         ┬  
    ·         ╰── binding `s` declared here
 12 │     tokio::task::spawn(s.run());
    ·                        ───┬───  
    ·                           ╰───── borrowed value does not live long enough
    ·                           │     
    ·                           ╰───── argument requires that `s` is borrowed for `'static`
 13 │ }
    · ┬  
    · ╰── `s` dropped here while still borrowed
────╯
```

I found a couple workarounds, but happy to hear a if there is something better:

If I change the fn signature to move self instead of borrowing:

```
run(self)  // removed the &.
```

Or if I can't change the signature, at the call site I can add an explicit move:

```
tokio::task::spawn(async move { s.run().await });
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The ways you've already found are the ways. I'm not sure I understand your question: the compiler doesn't do that because those are the language's rules.

Comment: In your example, `s` is not borrowed by `spawn`, it's borrowed by `run`, which, in turn, passes that borrow into an anonymous `impl Future` which is then moved into `spawn`. And it is this last step what causes the compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, the explicit `async move` block is the best way.

The unnamed `Future` type that `run` returns borrows `self`, but `tokio::task::spawn` requires a `'static` future (i.e. one that does not borrow). You can't just "move self into the future" because that would require that `run` return a different type. However you can create a new future, via `async move`, that contains `self`, and just calls out to `run`.